# FSharp function/method body executes as Script, but does not execute as source file at runtime

Tags: c#, methods, module, f#, interop

Thanx for going through this long-Q and your help is plenty appreciated.
So, the situation is that I have a piece of FSharp code contained in a module with modules nested in and there is a CSharp code that calls a method from a public type within one of these nested modules. Please see the code below: 
Array.Parallel.map
    namespace MachineLearning.Predictions

```
// refrences to other namespaces/modules

module Sample = 
    // so this is set at compile
    let cons1 = MachinLearning.Example.Calc.comp(something)     

module MulRegression =  
    // this too is set at compile
    let cons2 = MachinLearning.Example.Calc.comp(something)
    // other code 

    type public OPrediction() =    
        // this runs ok and gets the resulting value 
        let valu0 = 
            MachinLearning.Example.Calc.comp(something)

        let valu1 = cons2    // debugger jumps out as if no cons2 exist

        member this.OPred(atp) = 
           // a bunch of values, functions, etc, from other modules

module LogRegression =  
    // other code

    type public CPrediction() =        
       member this.CPred(atp) = 
           // a bunch of values, functions, etc, from other modules
```

First, Required namespaces are opened by `using NamespacePath;`" modules are opened by "`using static ModulePath;`" and the whole solution builds without any problems. The FSharp code on its own generates the required results within FSharp environment (FSI, call from another FSharp code). Now, the issue occurs with CSharp code calling methods `prediction.CPred(inp)` in module `MachineLearning.Predictions.LogRegression` and method `OPrediction.OPred(inp)` in module `MachineLearning.Predictions.MulRegression`. If I assign a known-value (e.g., `inp`, `inp + 7`, or `2`) as the return-value of the methods, everything is fine. With the body intact, as soon as the body hits the first line with some value from outside the scope of the method (say, `let len = pidz.Length`), the execution simply jumps out. There are no errors, no nothing, it jumps out with no return value!!!

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
// FSharp test script runs perfectly and produces the results.
//------------------------------------------------------------

// #load directives


module Test1 =
    // open statements 

    let op = OPrediction()
    let res = op.OPred(717)
    do printfn "%A" res

module Test2 =
    // open statements

    let cp = CPrediction()
    let res = cp.CPred(800.)
    do printfn "%A" res


//------------------------------------------------------------
// CSharp calling method does not return anything. 
//------------------------------------------------------------  

// GET: ODetails/OPredict/1
public Int32 OPredict(int id) {
    var op = new OPrediction();     // so far, A-OK!

    // 1) OPred(id) is defined like OPred(id) = 2. then result is produced.
    // 2) OPred keeps its def, then when 'stepping-in', the first line 
    //    involving other than 'id' or constant, debugger jumps out to
    //    get the next item in queue and the story repeats.  
    var res = (Int32)op.OPred(id);  
    return res;
}

// GET: CDetails/CPredict/1
public Int32 CPredict(double point) {
    var cp = new CPrediction();
    var res = (Int32)cp.CPred(point);
    return res;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: After a day of ... : For me it has gotten just more wierd. Within the scope of type `OPrediction`, it is as if the debugger does not recognise any of values and identifiers defined using stuff from other namespaces/modules in the top Namespace `MachineLearning.Predictions` nor any of the nested modules including the module that contains the type itself. On the other hand, the debugger seems to recognise the values set using a direct call to said fuction within the body of the type.

**UPDATE 2**: After inspecting the whole damn thing piece-by-piece throug FSI:

1. The issue was a runtime-thing. Whether the method was called from Program.fs or from CSharp, the problem persisted. It is wierd that I do not encounter the issue when running the code as a script.
2. The problem was specifically with the bluemountaincapital `Deedle` dataframe and conversion to `float`, in an expression involving `Array.Parallel.map`.
3. I am not certain whether the problem was with accessing a dataframe's rows in parallel or conversion of dataframe columns to `float`. Just to be safe, I fixed both by explicitly converting each column of dataframe to `float` and reconstructing the result into a new frame, and taking a lengthier and less-elegant non-parallel path, and now the code runs without a hitch - so far.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean, "it jumps out with no return value"? Are you talking about stepping through in the debugger? Or something else? Also, there's a lot of F# code here, and most of it is irrelevant to the question: if you could trim the irrelevant parts, it might make it easier to understand: I can't tell from the code what parts are relevant or not. Finally, since you're having problems calling your F# code from C#, it would also help if you would show us the part of the C# code that calls the F# functions.

Comment: 1) If I just build the solution and go to run the result, I do not get any errors/warnings at any point but then again, no results either. 2) "Jumping Out" is when I step into the debugger ...

Comment: To me it sounds like your issue is with the initialization of F# modules: when using an all-F# solution, the F# compiler of course knows when values from other F# modules are required, and when to automagically invoke any module initialization code (required e.g. to produce the value of ``Sample.cons1`` or ``MulRegression.cons2``—unlike your question seems to imply, these are not calculated at compile time!). The C# compiler, on the other hand, may not know there's any initialization code, so you will have to build yourself a kludge to make sure you can manually initialize all required values.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The problem was specifically with the bluemountaincapital `Deedle` dataframe and conversion to `float`, in an expression involving `Array.Parallel.map`.

**2)** I am not certain whether the problem was with accessing a dataframe's rows in parallel or conversion of dataframe columns to `float`. Just to be safe, I fixed both by explicitly converting each column of dataframe to `float` and reconstructing the result into a new frame, and taking a lengthier and less-elegant non-parallel path, and now the code runs without a hitch - so far.

**3)** I am not sure if the process of explicitly converting each column and reconstructing the frame is a good idea or not. For a very large dataframe, it may be problematic, then again it may not ...!!!